# Catastrophic backtracking issue with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new in working with Regular Expressions and currently facing a problem regarding that.

I am trying to build a regular expression that matches string in below format:

`OptionalStaticText{OptionalStaticText %(Placholder) OptionalStaticText {OptionalSubSection} OptionalStaticText} OptionalStaticText`

Each `Section` or `Subsection` is denoted by `{...}`. Each `Placeholder` is denoted by `%(...)`. Each `Section` or `Subsection` can have arbitrary permutation of `OptionalStaticText`, `%(Placholder)`, and `OptionalSubSection`.

For this, I have created a regular expression which is as below, (also can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/gA8pC9/2)).

```
/^(?:(?:(?:[\s\w])*(?:({(?:(?:[\s\w])*[%\(\w\)]+(?:[\s\w])*)+(?:{(?:(?:[\s\w])*[%\(\w\)]+(?:[\s\w])*)+})*})+)(?:[\s\w])*)+)$/g
```

This expression matches perfectly the valid strings (for example: `abc {st1 %(ph1) st11} int {st2 %(ph2) st22}{st3 %(ph3) st33 {st31 %(ph4) st332}} cd` as can be tested in the link given.

However, it causes a timeout whenever, the input string in invalid(for example: `abc {st1 %(ph1) st11} int {st2 %(ph2) st22}{st3 %(ph3) st33 {st31 %(ph4) st332}} c-d`, `-` is not a valid character as per the `[\s\w]` character group).

Such invalid string causes timeout via Catastrophic backtracking, which can also be tested in the above link.

I must have made some rookie mistake, but not sure what. Is there a change I should make to avoid this?

Thank You.

Comment: I don't think that regex alone is the right tool for that job. Even if you can do it, the resulting regex will be completely unreadable to most human beings so you will have a serious maintenance problem. You could try to write a parser instead.

Comment: Start to remove useless groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you have timeout issue its probably because of this `[%\(\w\)]+`
which is a class of characters contained in the form you're looking for.

Use the form itself instead.

`^(?:(?:[\s\w]*(?:({(?:[\s\w]*%\(\w*\)[\s\w]*)+(?:{(?:[\s\w]*%\(\w*\)[\s\w]*)+})*})+)[\s\w]*)+)$`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      (?:
           [\s\w]* 
           (?:
                (                             # (1 start)
                     {
                     (?:
                          [\s\w]* 
                          % \( \w* \) 
                          [\s\w]* 
                     )+
                     (?:
                          {
                          (?:
                               [\s\w]* 
                               % \( \w* \) 
                               [\s\w]* 
                          )+
                          }
                     )*
                     }
                )+                            # (1 end)
           )
           [\s\w]* 
      )+
 )
 $
```

Comment: this regex matches till the end of the string but doesn't work on several test cases see (this link)[https://regex101.com/r/wT7jV3/1]. It has also an unneeded level of brackets (the first one)

Comment: @GsusRecovery - Yes it does have an unneeded nested cluster group. Big deal, I don't try to educate people on style. I just took his regex and fixed his backtracking problem. How you know what _his_ test cases are I don't know, but is that really the issue ? And show me the evidence that a single nested cluster group is a single microsecond slower than without it.

Comment: you can test on you own on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wT7jV3/1) ( if i had properly formatted the link above): without the external group the regex engine skips 71 steps, but it's not the point. I've extracted the test case from the string description the OP put in the question: ``OptionalStaticText{OptionalStaticText %(Placholder) OptionalStaticText {OptionalSubSection} OptionalStaticText} OptionalStaticText``

Comment: `skips 71 steps` I'm trying to add up how many microseconds each _step_ is to get a total, but I just can't. Engines exist in a compiled world, not a step world. As far as online testers, they are useless trash.. filled with noise.

Comment: i've pointed out something that is not ok with your answer (mainly the cases, the external bracket are just an addiction you can ignore) just to induce you to fix them, if you are able do it please. I'm honestly curious if a pure straight regex solution exists (mainly in javascript).

Comment: @GsusRecovery - You've pointed out nothing wrong with this answer, but something trivial and useless towards solving his backtracking issue, which was his question. I've reworked _his_ regex to solve that. I didn't rewrite it for him, that's his job. Let him start another question for anything further. Let's move on to your solution.

Comment: A further note that JS does not support recursion, so the OP is down the rabbit hole trying to use a regex to validate this balanced text sample.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to match the line exactly from the start `^` to end `$` with all these nested repetition operators (`*` or `+`) cause the catastrophic backtracking.

Remove the end anchor `$` and simply check the length of the input string against the length of the match.

I've rewritten the regex to work alse in the cases where the optional sections were removed too:

```
^(?:[\w \t]*(?:{(?:[\w \t]*|%\(\w+\)|{(?:[\w \t]*|%\(\w+\))+})+})?)+
```

[**Online Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uI6vL6/3)

**Legenda**

```
^                              # Start of the line
(?:                            # OPEN NGM1 - Non matching group 1
  [\w \t]*                     # regex word char or space or tab (zero or more)
  (?:                          # OPEN NMG2
    {                          # A literal '{'
    (?:                        # OPEN NMG3 with alternation between:
      [\w \t]*|                # 1. regex word or space or tab (zero or more)
      %\(\w+\)|                # 2. A literal '%(' follower by regex word and literal ')'
      {(?:[\w \t]*|%\(\w+\))+} # 3. 
    )+                         # CLOSE NMG3 - Repeat one or more time
    }                          # A literal '}'
  )?                           # CLOSE NMG2 - Repeat zero or one time
)+                             # CLOSE NMG1 - Repeat one or more time
```

**Regex Schema**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Js Demo**

```js
var re = /^(?:[\w \t]*(?:{(?:[\w \t]*|%\(\w+\)|{(?:[\w \t]*|%\(\w+\))+})+})?)+/;

var tests = ['OptionalStaticText{OptionalStaticText %(Placeholder) OptionalStaticText {OptionalSubSection} OptionalStaticText} OptionalStaticText', '{%(Placeholder) OptionalStaticText {OptionalSubSection}}', 'OptionalStaticText{%(Placeholder)} OptionalStaticText', 'abc {st1 %(ph1) st11} int {st2 %(ph2) st22}{st3 %(ph3) st33 {st31 %(ph4) st332}} cd', 'abc {st1 %(ph1) st11} int {st2 %(ph2) st22}{st3 %(!ph3!) st33 {st31 %([ph4]) st332}} cd', 'abc {st1 %(ph1) st11} int {st2 %(ph2) st22}{st3 %(ph3) st33 {st31 %(ph4) st332}} c-d',  'abc {st1 %(ph1) st11} int {st2 %(ph2) st22}{st3 %(ph3) st33 {st31 %(ph4) st332}} cd'];
var m;

while(t = tests.pop()) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += '"' + t + "'<br/>";
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += 'Valid string? ' + ( (t.match(re)[0].length == t.length) ? '<font color="green">YES</font>' : '<font color="red">NO</font>') + '<br/><br/>';
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: Just an fyi. `Trying to match the line exactly from the start ^ to end $ with all these nested repetition operators (* or +) cause the catastrophic backtracking` - This by itself does _not_ cause backtracking issues. Like this `^(?:a(?:b(?:(?:c(?:d+)+)*)*)+)$` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a parser to parse such structured strings, and the parser itself would allow you to check the validity of the strings. For example (not complete):

```
var sample = "OptionalStaticText{OptionalStaticText %(Placholder) OptionalStaticText {OptionalSubSection} OptionalStaticText} OptionalStaticText";

function parse(str){

  return parseSection(str);

  function parseSection(str) {
    var section = new Section();
    var pointer = 0;

    while(!endOfSection()){

      if (placeHolderAhead()){
        section.push(parsePlaceHolder());
      } else if (sectionAhead()){
        section.push(parseInnerSection());
      } else {
        section.push(parseText());
      }
    }

    return section;

    function eat(token){
      if(str.substr(pointer, token.length) === token) {
        pointer += token.length;
        section.textLength += token.length;
      } else {
        throw ("Error: expected " + chr + " but found " + str.charAt(pointer));
      }
    }

    function parseInnerSection(){
      eat("{");
      var innerSection = parseSection(str.substr(pointer));
      pointer += innerSection.textLength;
      eat("}");
      return innerSection;
    }

    function endOfSection(){
      return (pointer >= str.length)
            || (str.charAt(pointer) === "}");
    }

    function placeHolderAhead(){
      return str.substr(pointer, 2) === "%(";
    }

    function sectionAhead(){
      return str.charAt(pointer) === "{";
    }

    function parsePlaceHolder(){
      var phText = "";
      eat("%(");
      while(str.charAt(pointer) !== ")") {
        phText += str.charAt(pointer);
        pointer++;
      }
      eat(")");
      return new PlaceHolder(phText);
    }

    function parseText(){
      var text = "";

      while(!endOfSection() && !placeHolderAhead() && !sectionAhead()){
        text += str.charAt(pointer);
        pointer++;
      }
      return text;
    }
  }
}

function Section(){
  this.isSection = true;
  this.contents = [];
  this.textLength = 0;

  this.push = function(elem){
    this.contents.push(elem);
    if(typeof elem === "string"){
      this.textLength += elem.length;
    } else if(elem.isSection || elem.isPlaceHolder) {
      this.textLength += elem.textLength;
    }
  }

  this.toString = function(indent){
    indent = indent || 0;
    var result = "";
    this.contents.forEach(function(elem){
      if(elem.isSection){
        result += elem.toString(indent+1);
      } else {
        result += Array((indent*8)+1).join(" ") + elem + "\n";
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}

function PlaceHolder(text){
  this.isPlaceHolder = true;
  this.text = text;
  this.textLength = text.length;

  this.toString = function(){
    return "PlaceHolder: \"" + this.text + "\"";
  }
}


console.log(parse(sample).toString());

/* Prints:
OptionalStaticText
        OptionalStaticText 
        PlaceHolder: "Placholder"
         OptionalStaticText 
                OptionalSubSection
         OptionalStaticText
 OptionalStaticText
*/
```